Can you pair a Ps Portal from a distance?
I am moving abroad for a while and am considering buying a Ps Portal to use my PS5 from there. I have seen online that this can be done provided my internet is sufficiently strong (which I believe it will be; the one at home surely is). However, one question I have not seen answered yet is:
Can I pair the Ps Portal to a PS5 from a distance?
I.e., if I buy a Ps Portal at the country I am moving to, can I pair it from there to my PS5 back home and start playing? Or do I have to buy it at my home country, pair it and then travel?
Thanks in advance!

Typically speaking, pairing devices requires to be on the same network (or at least in the pairing range). Otherwise, anybody could pair any system to any device.

@Wondercricket I figure that could be the case, but it could perhaps pair directly if I use the same account, use a QR code, two-step verification, etc. That is why I asked this specific question

You definitely can play with PS Portal from abroad, providing that the initial setup on the PS5 was completed:

enable Remote Play for your account
keep the Internet connection while in Rest mode


It's safer to test this first when you're at home, in case you missed something...
Other important things you should remember:

The console has to remain in Rest mode, so when disconnecting the PS Portal it's important to NOT turning it off. Always put the PS5 again in Rest mode, or you will be locked out of Remote play for the whole journey!
It's recommended to set PS Portal to Performance mode, in order to reduce the latency

More information here.

Would you happen to know whether any of these setup requirements have to be done with the Ps Portal close-by? The ones you have shown seem to only require setting up the PS5 itself, and the video did not mention anything too different…

@Gauss none of them, I'd say. But I think it's better to test the first connection while near your PS5
